# DI in .Net Core MVC 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I see in many MVC examples how to register your interfaces in the `ConfigurationServices` method of the `Startup` Class. This is fine when you have your code all written within the MVC app, but in the 'Real World' this wouldn't necessarily be the case.

I have a class library project in the form

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IMyRepository _myRepository;
    public MyService(IMyRepository myRepository)
    {
        _myRepository = myRepository;
    }
    .......
```

Now  in my controller I have a constructor of the form:

```
public HomeController(IConfigurationRoot config, IMyServcie myService)
{
    ......
```

The problem is, the `MyService` interfaces have not been registered with the DI Container and I don't really want to bloat the `ConfigurationServices` method with loads of `services.AddScoped<interface,class>()` lines of code for my other layers.

What do I need to do in my other layers (Repository and Service) to first register them here (both are .NET Core class library projects) and then wire those containers into the parent container?

Comment: You have to register it somewhere. The bloat you are talking about is going to be somewhere there.

Comment: Yes I know, but I want to register my interfaces that are defined in my repository layer in the repository layer container. I then want to register my interfaces that are defined in my service layer in the service layer container and then additionally attach the repository container as an extension to the service layer container and then finally register the service layer container in the configuration service of the MVC project. I knew how to do this using Unity, but in core 1.0 and the in-built Di container I dont know how to do this.

Comment: `ConfigurationServices` is your composition root so that's where you register you services. The bloat has to go somewhere. You can create an extension method in your other layers and targets `ServiceCollection` and then populate as needed. They technically are not first registered there. they are registered in the composition root when you apply the extension method against `ServiceColection`

Comment: @Nkosi Have you an example. Including What I need to reference in the project.json files of the service and repository Layers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ConfigurationServices` is your composition root so that's where you register you services. The bloat has to go somewhere. You can create an extension method in your other layers and targets `IServiceCollection` and then populate as needed. They technically are not first registered there. they are registered in the composition root when you apply the extension method against `IServiceColection`

Your other layers would have to reference `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` in order to have access to the `IServiceCollection` interface.

IMO I don't think these extension methods need to be in your service or repository layers. Those layers don't need to know anything about how they are composed. You can just as easily put them in your composition root in another class and call them just as shown above if the end goal is to make the startup class cleaner. Or put in a separate extension project which is specifically for targeting .net core's DI framework.

Service Extension Layer

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyServices(this IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
    //...add other services
}
```

Repository Extension Layer

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyRepositories(this IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddScoped<IMyRepository, MyRepository >();
    //...add other services
}
```

And then in your composition root `ConfigureServices`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    //...other code

    services
        .AddMyServices()
        .AddMyRepositories();

    //...other code
}
```

UPDATE
based on comment you could just as easily call the `services.AddMyRepositories()` in the `AddMyServies` extension method as opposed to the main project itself

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyServices(this IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMyRepositories();
    services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
    //...add other services
}
```

And then in your composition root, `ConfigureServices` will only need to call the `AddMyServices`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    //...other code

    services.AddMyServices();

    //...other code
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi for this detailed answer. I have just one more question if I may. Where you register the '.AddMyRepositories();' Is it possible to register this in the service layer as opposed to the main project itself?

Comment: Yes it is an extension method and given that your services layer would be referencing the repository interface you could just as easily call the `services.AddMyRepositories()` in the `AddMyServies` extension method